# Spinner, AutoCompeteTextView padding after clicking outside (bug?)

Tags: android

I am using an `AutoCompleteTextView` (same goes with spinner dropdown). The items in the dropdown have proper paddings when it is populated. Here is what it looks like:
[image: Items when populated for the first time]

But if I don't select anything from the dropdown and click outside (now the dropdown is hidden), and then again click on the AutoCompleteTextView/Spinner, the shown dropdown doesn't have the paddings as it should. The left padding is gone.

[image: Items after user clicks outside and then clicks spinner again.]

I am using the adapter as:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, emailAddressesArray);
```

I have also tried `simple_dropdown_item_1line`, `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` and a custom `TextView` layout as the layout. Even the left padding for TextView is removed in this case.
Here is my `AutoCompleteTextView` from xml:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_login_edit_text"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
            android:hint="Your Email ID"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black_heading"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey_500"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Post your XML file ?

Comment: Done. I don't think it's xml though. It also happened with spinner in a totally different app.

Comment: u need to use array adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem. It's probably a bug. I had `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` in my styles, which was causing this problem. I'll be filing a bug report soon.

Comment: Did you ever file a bug report on this? I'm running into a similar issue just on simple spinners where if you deselect the list without selecting anything, the padding and formatting clears

Answer (score 0):

Use custom layout file and give it to in place of **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** suppose your layout file name is **spinner_back.xml**
then

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                       R.layout.spinner_back, emailAddressesArray);
```

file **spinner_back.xml**

```
 <TextView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: I have already added that I used a custom TextView for this. The padding is even then removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};  
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names  
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
        (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);  
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
       AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
       actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
       actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView  
       actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);  

}  

@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
    return true;  
}
}
```

**File: activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView1"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"  
    android:text="@string/what_is_your_favourite_programming_language_" />  

<AutoCompleteTextView  
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"  
    android:ems="10"  
    android:text="">  

    <requestFocus />  
</AutoCompleteTextView>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: How is this ArrayAdapter different than what I am using? I have tried and changed the item to `android.R.layout.select_dialog_item`. But still the same.

Comment: @VipulKumar copy above code n paste anther activity and check it...it's working fine for me...

Comment: I did. Completely new activity. When I click outside and click again on the AutoCompleteTexTview and start typing, the padding is gone.

Comment: @VipulKumar this code is working for me i think it's other problem... install apk in andriod phone n run it...

Comment: I am testing it on Android device. Nexus 6p, Android M. What is your configuration?

Comment: @VipulKumar please see the Image

Comment: Have you tried clicking outside and then clicking on the AutoCompleteTextView again and start typing again? when the dropdown is shown again, this problem happens.

Comment: yes i click out side the AutocompleteTextview and start typing and dropdown show again... there no problem working fine..paste ur **gradle** code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by setting again the adapter and clearing the `AutoCompleteTextView` focus on dismiss.

On kotlin:

```kotlin
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
    context,
    R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT,
    YOUR_ARRAY_OF_TRING_ITEMS
)

autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

autoCompleteTextView.setOnDismissListener {
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
    autoCompleteTextView.clearFocus()
}
```